# DropDownList missing font or string encoding issue

Tags: winforms, unicode, .net-3.5, cjk

I have some Korean text I need to display on my WinForm. The text displays fine in my ListBox control. The same text does not display in my DropDownList control. Both controls have a font of Arial 8pt. The ItemHeight property for both controls is 14. I can't spot any differences in the properties of these controls that would mean one control displays the text correctly and the other doesn't.

I have read in [the following article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1096441/what-does-it-mean-the-text-in-control-appear-to-be-all-squares) that the problem is either caused by the font or the character encoding.

From what I can gather, the code uses standard .NET strings. There are no character conversions taking place. The required font to display Korean must be installed, otherwise I would not be able to view it in one control and not another. What am I doing wrong?

[image: Korean correctly displayed]

[image: Korean incorrectly displayed]

Comment: Did you see this [other SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4157398/combobox-with-segoe-ui-and-japanese-text)? It has already received an answer but is not (yet) accepted, maybe is relevant for you also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I resolved this by changing the font from Arial 8pt to **[Arial Unicode MS](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/287247)** 8.25pt. As [Luis Quijada](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1203135/luis-quijada) pointed out when he suggested I look at this question

[ComboBox with Segoe UI and Japanese text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4157398/combobox-with-segoe-ui-and-japanese-text)

Changing the font from Arial to [Arial Unicode MS](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/287247) was an acceptable workaround for me. I'm not sure which languages Arial is supposed to support. It's possibly a Microsoft bug that Arial works in the ListBox but not in the DropDownList for the Korean text.